# How to check email is already in database or not in django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

I want to add a functionality in registration form that if email is already in database than display massage ie this email is already register.
i am trying this with the following code but this is not working

accounts/forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    # email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        fields = ["username","email","password1","password2"]
        model = get_user_model()
        
    def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            if email in User.objects.all():
                raise forms.ValidationError("This email is already register")
            return email
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        # self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `UserCreateForm.clean_email` you are not checking it the correct way. You are checking by this `if email in User.objects.all()`. Here the `email` is not a a `User` object. `User.objects.all()` returns a `queryset` of `User` objects. Since, `email` is not an instance of `User` your condition checking is  not successful. Rather do the following to check if an user already exists with the provided email

```py
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if email.split('.')[-1] !=  'edu' :
        raise forms.ValidationError("Only .edu email addresses allowed")
    if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("User with that email already exists")
    return email
```

Make sure you set `email` in your `User` model to be `unique`.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the validation in wrong way, it should be as,

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    # rest of your code

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Only .edu email addresses allowed")
        return email
```